# .htacces RewriteRule problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is working:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})$                /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3 [L]
```

with this URL:

```
http://localhost/showCategory/590/10
```

Now I want to work with this too:

```
http://localhost/showCategory/590/transport/10
```

The rule I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/([a-z\-_0-9\+]*)/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})$               /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3 [L]
```

How to change the `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works with both URLs

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/)?showCategory/([0-9]+)(?:/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?([0-9]+)/?$  /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3 [L]
```

I also simplified the {0,1} with ? which does the same.

The key is in `(?:/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?`, explanation:

```
(?:                   Non-capturing group, so what's in here will not be put in any $n
  /                   Match the slash
  [A-Za-z0-9_-]+      Match any word with letters/numbers/dashes/underscores
)?                    Close non-capturing group, and the ? means it's optional
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/mp/(.*)(/{0,1})$                 /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/(.*)/mp/(.*)(/{0,1})$           /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3&$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*$                         /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory/([0-9]*)/[a-z\-_0-9\+]*/([0-9]*)(/{0,1})$      /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3 [L]

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/){0,1}showCategory$                 /main.php?id=0&il[lang]=$1 [L]
I use these lines
and localhost/showCategory/ is OK
localhost/showCategory/0/1 is OK
localhost/showCategory/0/2 stays on the first page... not good
what is the problem?

Comment: If .../0/1 works but .../0/2 doesn't, it's probably because you're not using the right parameter.
If you're using PHP, in your php script do `print_r($_GET)` and see if you're using the right param

Comment: array(3) { ["id"]=>  string(1) "0" ["il"]=>  &array(1) { ["lang"]=>  string(0) "" } ["sh"]=>  &NULL }

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}/)?showCategory/([0-9]+)/[a-z-_0-9+]+/([0-9]+)/?$ /main.php?id=$2&il[lang]=$1&page=$3 [L]
```